# div's have margins when i set margin to 0 for div, and body

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to get a `div` called `touch-container` to hold a `canvas` with 3 div's on top. I'm sizing them using `javascript` as well.

The problem is that each of the 3 div's have a `margin` which takes up the rest of the space in the *container* even though i specifically state 0 `margin`.

Here is a jsFiddle, if you inspect, you can see the `margin` [**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xwkgwhf2/)

**HTML**:

```
<div id = "touch-container">
    <div id = "touch-left" class = "touch-control"></div>
    <div id = "touch-middle" class = "touch-control"></div>
    <div id = "touch-right" class = "touch-control"></div>
    <canvas id = "canvas" width = "960" height = "560"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#touch-container{
  width: 964px;
  height: 560px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.touch-control{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

#touch-left{
  background-color: red;
}

#touch-middle{
  background-color: green;
}

#touch-right{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

**JS**:

```
var leftTouch = document.getElementById('touch-left');
var upTouch = document.getElementById('touch-middle');
var rightTouch = document.getElementById('touch-right');

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = (canvas.width > canvas.height ? canvas.width : canvas.height);
var height = (canvas.height > canvas.width ? canvas.width : canvas.height);

leftTouch.style.width = (width/ 4) + 'px';
leftTouch.style.height = height + 'px';

upTouch.style.width = (width/ 2) + 'px';
upTouch.style.height = height + 'px';

rightTouch.style.width = (width/ 4) + 'px';
rightTouch.style.height = height + 'px';

ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

I've colored them in so it should be a black square on the **bottom**, then from **left** to **right**, a red, green and blue square that takes up `25%, 50% 25%` of the *container* respectively so you wont even be able to see the black `canvas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add any `float` in your elements(squares) so the squares don't know how they should be located, You most use `float:left;` to force squares to be in a same line and `display:inline-block;` wont works in your case (it just works for text only):

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xwkgwhf2/5/)

**css**:

```
#touch-container{
    width: 964px;
    height: 560px;
    display: block;/* new update */
    margin: 0;
}

#touch-left{
    background-color: red;
    float:left;/* new update from here to below */
    display:block;
}

#touch-middle{
    background-color: green;
    float:left;/* new update from here to below */
    display:block;
}

#touch-right{
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;/* new update from here to below */
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is how i wanted it where they were side by side, the canvas should be under but i can fix that, thankyou :)

Comment: @RachelDockter canvas is under all 3 squares (check jsfiddle i provide). If this is answer please set it as an answer for other viewers

Answer (score 0):

Margin refers to the spacing between block and inline-block level elements. Since divs are block elements, they stack on top of each other, and margin: 0 removes any space between them.

If you are looking to place the divs on top of the canvas element, you can achieve that with absolute positioning.

```
.touch-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Then you can use your javascript to set the 'left' property of each div to where you want it, or positioning them individually with the css.

Comment: Thanks this works to put the divs on top of the canvas